# There is some intuitive idea of Pascal's 's theorem in Projective Geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history, projective-geometry

In projective geometry, [Pascal's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) (formulated by Blaise Pascal when he was 16 years old) determines that a hexagon inscribed in a conic, the lines that contain the opposite sides intersect in collinear points, ie if the six vertices a hexagon are located on a circle and three pairs of opposite sides intersect three intersection points are colinear.
It is a generalization of the [theorem of Pappus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem).

No doubt a theorem fantastic! Mainly, as well as aesthetic appeal, by Fanto is not clear (at least as far as I know). And it is this that motivates my questions.

> 1) There is some intuitive way to see Pascal's theorem?

What I mean is something in the same spirit of [Java Aplet](http://www.ies.co.jp/math/java/geo/gaikaku/gaikaku.html) on the Sum of Outer Angles of a Polygon Theorem.

> 2) Pascal conceived his theorem as a generalization of Pappus theorem? The proof of Pascal gives some clue as to how he got the idea theorem?

Comment: One thing you can observe is that all non-degenerate conics in the (complex) projective plane are equivalent, so you can reduce (the non-degenerate case) to the case of a circle.

Comment: Here is an applet you can play with: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Pascal.shtml

Comment: I don’t know Pascal’s proof of the theorem, but here are a few approaches:  1.  A simple argument using projective linear isomorphisms as in §3.2 of http://wwwth.itep.ru/~gorod/ps/stud/projgeom/list.html.  2.  By Bézout’s theorem (c.f. §6.2.5 in http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf).  This argument is generalized by Max Noether’s Fundamentalsatz (c.f. Fulton’s introduction to algebraic curves, p. 123).  3.  By Cayley-Bacharach theorem (c.f. Griffith and Harris, p. 673).  Hope that helps.